# Orbeon / web services and action

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I would like to use webservices and actions that i've created in my reusables sections which have been saved in a form named library.

I've copied actions and webservices from the source view in template.xml file.

Unfortunatelly, it does not work because controls from reusables sections are invisibles when i try to reach them in the destination field of the action.

Does anyone have a trick?

Regards,
Philippe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, the issue is that when you create a section template and reuse it in another form, Form Runner encapsulates that section in an XBL component. Because the XBL encapsulation, services that are declared at the "top level" in the form don't have access to the controls within the XBL component.

So I think that the solution here is to create your own XBL that contains the controls and the web services, but keep in mind that:

1. Creating your own XBL is more complicated than creating a section template. You can find information about this in the [Guide to Using and Writing XBL Components](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components-guide).
2. Once you have an XBL component, you can setup Form Builder to show it along the other controls on the left side bar. You can find more on how to add an XBL component to the toolbox in this [Toolbox section](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-builder#TOC-Toolbox). However, note that XBL components are not sections, but closer to controls. They are bound to just one node in your instance, and you add them to the form in Form Builder as you would add a control, i.e. they go into the cell of a table.